# URL getting Appended when using Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a URL say `/Registration/GetName.aspx/?language=English`

When i click on a Asp.net Button on the same Page and say  `Response.Redirect("CheckLoginName.aspx");`

It gives me a weird URL

```
/Registration/GetName.aspx/CheckLoginName.aspx
```

What should i do

Please Help?

Comment: You should remove the trailing `/` before the query string. Your URL should be `/Registration/GetName.aspx?language=English`. Another option is to have `Response.Redirect("../CheckLoginName.aspx");` I think this should also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use "~/" inside your Redirect

So your code will look something like this

```
Response.Redirect("~/CheckLoginName.aspx");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: My Page is inside a folder what then?

Comment: in that case you should add the folder name as well. `Response.Redirect("~/YOURFOLDER/CheckLoginName.aspx");`

Comment: I think a relative path would be a better solution, since it is location independant. With your solution, if he moves the file, he will need to change his code as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the trailing `/` before the query string, since it serves no purpose. Your URL should be `/Registration/GetName.aspx?language=English`. Another option is to have `Response.Redirect("../CheckLoginName.aspx");` This should also work.

I think a solution using a relative path is better, since it is location independant. If you move these two files to another URL, there will be no need for code changes.